# Can i post rich-text message via the incoming webhook in teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

According to microsoft docs, I can post a plain text to teams channel:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Hello World\"}" <YOUR WEBHOOK URL>`

can i post a rich-text message, such as bold text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. HTML and markdown is supported in the incoming webhooks. try these:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Hello <b>World</b>\"}" <YOUR WEBHOOK URL>
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Hello **World**\"}" <YOUR WEBHOOK URL>`

Comment: Awesome feature! - NOT
Any idea how to disable this?
Let's say I want to post text "A_B_C" but it get's shown as A _B_ C

Comment: Did you find a solution on how to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Try Markdown:

`curl -H “Content-type: application/json” -d “{\”text\”: \”**Hello** world\”}” <YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!

To send a message through your Office 365 Connector or incoming webhook, you post a JSON payload to the webhook URL. Typically this payload will be in the form of an Office 365 Connector Card.

You can also use this JSON to create cards containing rich inputs, such as text entry, multi-select, or picking a date and time. The code that generates the card and posts to the webhook URL can be running on any hosted service. These cards are defined as part of actionable messages, and are also supported in cards used in Teams bots and Messaging extensions.
...
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using